# dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid Exporter Plugin - How to export a particular column

Tags: dojo, grid, exporter

How to export a particular column from dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid exporter plugin.

Thanks
Ravikanth

Comment: stackoverflow is about helping you, not writing code for you... You should tell us what you tried, give some code example, some extra details on your setup....

Comment: Hi Ben,

I am using dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid with dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/exporter/CSVWriter export plugin.

the below code is exporting the complete grid

dijit.byId("grid").exportGrid("csv", function(str){
        alert(str);
});

Is any option available to export a single column of the Grid?

Answer (score 0):

I could able to retrieve items and parse single column using the below code.

```
store._fetchItems("",
function(items){
    for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++)
    {
        console.log(items[i].Column1);
    }
},
function(error){
        console.log(error);
```

});

Thanks